# Creating installers for my products

Tags: macos, installation, apfs

my team develops several products for both Windows and Mac. Until now we used Vise-x for creating installers for Mac (and install shield for windows), for some reason searching (using Vise-x) on the APFS hangs. 
Due to that reason we want to replace vise-x with a new installer-creator.

Can anyone recommend on a good, robust installer creator (which has full support) for Mac (or even better- cross platforms) ?

Comment: The use of installers on the Mac platform is strongly discouraged. Please make a standard application bundle (which an be distributed as Zip archive). If you need to install drivers etc. into the system you could use Apples pkg-format or offer to install such things from within your application.

Comment: I need to display a localized license agreement, does the pkg support it ?

Comment: Of course, read the documentation for `pkgbuild` and `pkgutil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Qt Installer Framework - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/osx-deployment.html
That simple installer framework for any application type. You no need know Qt for this purposes.